# ratio word problem

Tags: ratio

2kg beef is cut into 3 pieces A, B and C. The weights of A and B are in the ratio 2:3. If the weight of C is 0.5kg, find the weights of A and B.

Comment: $2=2x+3x+0.5\to x=0.3 \to A=0.6 B=0.9$

Answer (score 0):

Take away $C$ from the total of 2kg. Split the rest of the meat up (how much is "the rest of the meat?) according to the given ratio. Problem solved.